# Motores en MySQL para creación de tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

> Cuando creas una tabla que necesita permitir el uso de relaciones
>   entre ellas, haces uso de `InnoDB` y la creas mas o menos de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   tags JSON NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

> Si bien no necesitas, el uso de las relaciones entre tablas puedes
>   valerte para el mismo ejemplo pero del motor `MyISAM` mas o menos del
>   siguiente modo

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   tags JSON NOT NULL
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

> Sin embargo con MySQL puedes trabajar el tema de tablas con el motor
>   `FEDERATED` con una sintáxis similar a la siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   tags JSON NOT NULL
)ENGINE=FEDERATED
 CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
```

Las preguntas son:

> 1. ¿En que escenario se usa una tabla federada?
> 2. ¿Cuando se usa una tabla federada aunque no declares el uso de `InnoDB` se siguen manteniendo las características de `InnoDB` como por ejemplo que permita usar tablas relacionadas?
> 3. ¿Si se usa una tabla federada, la sintaxis de la misma debe ser la misma en el servidor local que en el servidor remoto?

Comment: Es (son) interesante(s) tu(s) pregunta(s), aunque creo que se mueve en el límite de las preguntas *demasiado amplias*.  La pregunta 2 no es clara: *...se siguen manteniendo sus características*  ¿las características de quién?

Comment: es cierto lo agregaré a la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu pregunta me parece interesante, así que me animo a responder.

### 1. ¿En que escenario se usa una tabla federada?

Según la documentación:

> El motor de almacenamiento `FEDERATED` permite acceder a los datos de
>   una base de datos remota de MySQL sin usar replicación o tecnología de
>   clúster. Consultar una tabla local `FEDERATED` automáticamente extrae
>   los datos de las tablas remotas (federadas). No se almacenan datos en
>   las tablas locales.
>
> <sub>[§ 16.8 The FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html), en la documentación de MySQL</sub>

---

### 2. ¿Cuando se usa una tabla federada aunque no declares el uso de InnoDB se siguen manteniendo las características de InnoDB como por ejemplo que permita usar tablas relacionadas?

Ya vimos en la nota anterior que *no se almacenan datos en las tablas locales* (la tabla federada es la tabla local). Los datos se almacenan en la tabla remota.

Luego, la documentación dice lo siguiente:

> Cuando crea una tabla utilizando uno de los motores de almacenamiento
>   estándar (como `MyISAM`, `CSV` o `InnoDB`), la tabla consiste en la
>   definición de la tabla y los datos asociados. Cuando crea una tabla
>   `FEDERATED`, **la definición de tabla es la misma**, pero el
>   almacenamiento físico de los datos se maneja en un servidor remoto.
>
> <sub>[§ 16.8.1 FEDERATED Storage Engine Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-description.html), en la documentación de MySQL</sub>

Si como dice la nota *la definición de tabla es la misma*, podemos deducir que el uso de tablas federadas en nada afecta las relaciones entre las demás tablas (a condición de que todas existan en el entorno local).

No obstante, puede haber algunas restricciones o incompatibilidades. Por ejemplo, en el apartado *[FEDERATED Storage Engine Notes and Tips](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-usagenotes.html)* (**el cual convendría leer y entender completamente antes de usar tablas federadas**) se advierte lo siguiente:

> Se debe tener cuidado al crear una tabla `FEDERATED` ya que la
>   definición de índice de una `MyISAM` equivalente u otra tabla puede no
>   ser compatible. Por ejemplo, la creación de una tabla `FEDERATED` con
>   un prefijo de índice en las columnas `VARCHAR`, `TEXT` o `BLOB`
>   fallará. La siguiente definición en `MyISAM` es válida:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `T1`(`A` VARCHAR(100),UNIQUE KEY(`A`(30))) ENGINE=MYISAM;
> ```
>
> El prefijo de clave en este ejemplo es incompatible con el motor
>   `FEDERATED` y la instrucción equivalente fallará:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `T1`(`A` VARCHAR(100),UNIQUE KEY(`A`(30))) ENGINE=FEDERATED
>   CONNECTION='MYSQL://127.0.0.1:3306/TEST/T1';
> ```
>
> Si es posible, intente separar la definición de columna e índice al
>   crear tablas tanto en el servidor remoto como en el servidor local
>   para evitar estos problemas de índice.
>
> <sub>[§ 16.8.3 FEDERATED Storage Engine Notes and Tips](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-usagenotes.html), en la documentación de MySQL</sub>

---

### 3. ¿Si se usa una tabla federada, la sintaxis de la misma debe ser la misma en el servidor local que en el servidor remoto?

Primeramente hay que decir que [la documentación indica dos formas de crear las tablas federadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create.html):

- Usando `CONNECTION`
- Usando `CREATE SERVER`

Veamos el ejemplo que da la misma documentación para crear la tabla remota:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Veamos ahora las dos formas en que se puede crear la tabla federada:

- **[Usando `CONNECTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html)**

  Si usamos `CONNECTION` la tabla federada se crearía así:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE federated_table (
      id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (id),
      INDEX name (name),
      INDEX other_key (other)
  )
  ENGINE=FEDERATED
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
  CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
  ```

  Si nos fijamos en la tabla remota y en la tabla local (federada), vemos que la sintaxis es casi la misma, sólo hay dos diferencias: **a**. que se debe especificar la cadena de conexión (`CONNECTION`) después de que se ha indicado el tipo de motor; **b**. el tipo de motor (`ENGINE`)  es `FEDERATED`, por supuesto.

  Ha de señalarse que `CONNECTION` reemplaza a la cláusula `COMMENT` utilizada en algunas versiones anteriores de MySQL.

  La cadena `CONNECTION` contiene la información necesaria para conectarse al servidor remoto que contiene la tabla que se utilizará para almacenar físicamente los datos. La cadena de conexión especifica el nombre del servidor, las credenciales de inicio de sesión, el número de puerto y la información de la base de datos / tabla. En el ejemplo, la tabla remota está en el servidor `remote_host`, usando el puerto `9306`. El nombre y número de puerto deben coincidir con el nombre de host (o la dirección IP) y el número de puerto de la instancia remota del servidor MySQL que quiera usar como su tabla remota.

  Más detalles sobre esta forma de crear la tabla federada se pueden consultar en el enlace, provisto ya en el título de este apartado.

---

- **[Usando `CREATE SERVER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-server.html)**

  Si estáS creando varias tablas `FEDERATED` en el mismo servidor, o si deseas simplificar el proceso de creación de tablas `FEDERATED`, puedes usar la instrucción `CREATE SERVER` para definir los parámetros de conexión del servidor, tal como lo harías con la cadena `CONNECTION`.

  Un ejemplo, según la documentación, sería este:

  ```
  CREATE SERVER fedlink
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
  OPTIONS (USER 'fed_user', HOST 'remote_host', PORT 9306, DATABASE 'federated');
  ```

  Ahora, para crear una tabla `FEDERATED` que use esta conexión, vamos a usar siempre la palabra clave `CONNECTION`, pero especificando el nombre que utilizamos en la declaración `CREATE SERVER`:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE test_table (
      id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (id),
      INDEX name (name),
      INDEX other_key (other)
  )
  ENGINE=FEDERATED
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
  CONNECTION='fedlink/test_table';
  ```

  El nombre de la conexión en este ejemplo contiene el nombre de la conexión (`fedlink`) y el nombre de la tabla (`test_table`) para enlazar, separados por una barra inclinada. Si especifica solo el nombre de conexión sin un nombre de tabla, en su lugar se usa el nombre de la tabla local.

  Para más detalles sobre `CREATE SERVER` ver la documentación (enlazada en el título de este apartado) y también al apartado [§ 13.1.16 CREATE SERVER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-server.html).

---

Como nota a esta pregunta 3, ten en cuenta lo que se afirma al final de la respuesta a tu pregunta 2 (sobre el problema de los índices en `MYISAM`). Cuando haya problemas de incompatibilidad, aunque uses el estilo  `CONNECTION` para la tabla federada, deberas escribir el `CREATE TABLE` de una forma que sea compatible.

En cuanto a la sintaxis de las consultas (`SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE` ...) no hay cambio ninguno, es la misma. Sin embargo, **hay restricciones en otro tipo de consultas**. Las mismas son indicadas en el ya referido apartado *16.8.3 FEDERATED Storage Engine Notes and Tips*.  Por ejemplo, no se permite usar `HANDLER`, no soporta `ALTER TABLE`, no soporta sentencias preparadas, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` es soportado, pero se comporta de forma diferente a la habitual, no soporta transacciones... etc. Ya lo dije más arriba: **leer con lupa la sección  16.8.3** :)